# How to copy row from one table to another and place it at desire position

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

hello I have a question how to copy row from one datatable to another and place it at particular position

For Example: I have two table one is clone and another Sessiondata I want to copy row from Sessiondata which ever index is coming in my Order variable, if my order variable is having 7 so i want the row which is in 7 position in Sessiondata and past it in clone i am doing it like this but it is not giving any result please help

```
   DataTable Clone = new DataTable();
   DataTable Sessiondata = Session["TblMaster"] as DataTable;
    for (int ChangeOrder = 0; ChangeOrder < dt.Rows.Count; ChangeOrder++)
    {
       int Order= Convert.ToInt32(Ordering.Rows[ChangeOrder]["Orderr"]);
       Clone.ImportRow(dt.Rows[Index]);
    }
```

Comment: What is Sessiondata and does it have any relations to the the variable dt from which you import rows? And what is Order and why you use always Index in your loop (are you importing always the same row?) I suppose that this code is really incomplete or totally wrong

Comment: My data is in Sessiondata  and their ordering in another table which is  Ordering what i want, what ever order is coming first in my Order Variavble i will get that row and past it in clone so i can display it according that order

Comment: Please see the comments ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use InsertAt method.

```
DataTable.Rows.InsertAt(DataRow,Index);
```

Here is how you can use it

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.Rows.InsertAt(DataRow,Index);
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad.. Please tell me in Datail

Comment: Check the code now.Replace name of dt with your datatable name in which you want to add row,